# Applying an armature modifier causes the clothing item to stick the sleeves up, how can I correct

Tags: rigging, armature, pose-mode

I modeled a shirt while in pose mode (a T pose) the armature rest pose was an A pose. I have changed the rest mode to the T pose and the shirt fits. I can transfer weights and it looks good, like this: [image]

But after I apply the armature modifier, the sleeves inexplicably stick up in the air, like this:
[image]

The shirt is parented to the armature and I have run out of ideas for how to correct this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Share your file. https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Looks like your cloth has a 2. Armature modifier on it.